# how do I distribute sqlce changes to clients

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

We have a SQL Compact Edition database that we use to store config setting in. It is working fine but I'd like to make changes to it to store additional information.

I am writing in C# using Winforms.

When I make changes to the database in our project, I need to send those changes out to the customer so they have the changes to go with the code changes. Our customers have remote laptops that we have to dial in an manually update. I'd prefer some method that is done automatically in code if possible. I'm not familiar enough with SQLCE to know what tools I have available to make these changes to the customers database. Each remote laptop has it's own SQLCE database with it's own code to access it. They are individual laptops not connected to a network.

What is a simple way to make compare and distribute changes from my project's database and make sure those changes are applied to the customer's database?

Comment: if you are going to down vote tell me WHY so I can fix the dang issue.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but, your question is confusing. Are you asking how to update the database and how to update the software to reflect these changes? If so, then that is a huge ask, we have no idea on your set up etc +1 for your comment

Comment: I will clarify that ty for the post.

Comment: @ErocM Don't let the frustration get to you, although downvoting with no feedback is a little rude. I suspect in this case people feel its a little broad and subjective. That said, I think you have a valid question, perhaps some minor edits would help.

Comment: @ChrisBallard I updated it, thx for the input. Do you see anything that I should clarify on?

Comment: @DaveRook I believe I have answered your questions. I need a way to update the client's databases with the changes the developers make.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit out "the best way" to perhaps "a simple way" to avoid any speculation that it is "primarily opinion based"

Comment: no worries, I know this is a real question, so just trying to ensure it doesn't get closed on you before someone can answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common problem. You ship your app with your database, then a new implementation requires a new field in your db (or some other schema change). Now how do you plan to update those customers that have already installed you app and have valuable data inside?

It is a complex task with many details to care of, but at its simplest form could be implemented in this way:

Add, inside you database, a new table with only one record and one column. This table will be called DBVersion, and the record contains a number that reflect the version of the database installed. (If you have a Configuration table you could simply add a record there)

Now you need to prepare an XML file to distribute with your updates

```
 <Scripts>
    <Script>
      <Version>1</Version>
      <Command>ALTER TABLE ......</Command>
    <Script>
    ....
 <Scripts>
```

At this point your application could read the Version number stored in your database and load the XML file executing every command associated with a Version number higher than the Version number stored in the database table.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I believe this is what I'm looking for! I'll give this a shot. Thanks again!